Convert this string into space separated by whitespace characters
I am trying to convert this string to vec or string representation similar to this.
"Text\n\0" ==> \"Text\" 0x0A 0x00
"Test1\t\x7FTest2" ==> \"Test1\" 0x09 0x7F \"Test2\"
What could be possible solution for this?
I have tried this, here is rust playground link
fn main() {
    // let test = "Text\n\0";

    let str1 = "Test1\t\x7FTest2";
    let mut res = vec![];

    for c in str1.chars() {
        res.push("\"");
        if c == '\t' {        
            res.push("\" 0x09");
        } else if c == '\x7F' {
            res.push("\" 0x7F");
        } else {
            res.push(c);
        }
    }

    println!("{}", res.join(" "));
    assert_eq!(res.join(" "), "\"Test1\" 0x09 0x7F \"Test2\"".to_string());
}


Ignoring the typos in your push(), then your main issue is that you're trying to push() two different types to res, i.e. &str and char

Any comments from the +3 upvotes? Simple questions are rarely upvoted here. This one contains literal typos and doesn't even compile. So I'm super curious about the upvotes, as they seem highly suspicious
